# Reading data from XML file and printing selected data

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, rss

I have a blog feed which is in an XML file:

```
<item>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>link</link>
    <pubDate>Date</pubDate>
</item>
```

I'm trying to get and echo out the above information, but it doesn't work. Here's my approach:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $index => $record) : ?>
    <div class="col-12">
        <?php 
            echo("
                <a class='item'>
                    <div class='item__card'>
                        $blogAuthor ->item ->link;
                        $blogTitle ->item ->title;
                        $blogDate ->item ->pubDate;
                    </div>
                </a>"
            );
        ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this is old school way of doing php, I wouldnt mix html and php like that. keep them separate, easier to read and understand in the future

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a simple XML file for demonstration purposes you can easily accomplish the goal using `DOMDocument`

```
$strxml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss>
    <item>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <link>link 1</link>
        <pubDate>Date 1</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <link>link 2</link>
        <pubDate>Date 2</pubDate>
    </item>
</rss>';


$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML( $strxml );

$col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('item');
foreach( $col as $item ){
    $title=$item->childNodes[1]->nodeValue;
    $link=$item->childNodes[3]->nodeValue;
    $pub=$item->childNodes[5]->nodeValue;

    echo $title,$link,$pub,'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using php you are missing `simplexml_load_string`

here is your code

```
<?php

$strxml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss>
    <item>
        <title>Title 1</title>
        <link>link 1</link>
        <pubDate>Date 1</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Title 2</title>
        <link>link 2</link>
        <pubDate>Date 2</pubDate>
    </item>
</rss>';

$col = simplexml_load_string($strxml); 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($col);

foreach( $col as $item ){
    $title=$item->title;
    echo $title.'<br />';
}
```

Output :

Title 1
Title 2